# accessing the initials field using the DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: .net, active-directory, account-management

I'm new to accessing Active Directory and I was advised to use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` but I can't find the `initials` variable any help ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do one of those things:

1) you can **extend** the normal `UserPrincipal` class to include additional items that you frequently need. This would be the cleanest solution, really. See the [MSDN docs on extending the user principal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384372%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), or [answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563395/looking-for-a-full-s-ds-am-sample-with-many-ad-extensions-already-written) for an example of how to extend the `UserPrincipal` class with additional properties

2) You could just "reach down" into the depths of your underlying `DirectoryEntry` and grab the data from there:

```
    DirectoryEntry de = YourUserPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

    if(de != null)
    {  
       var initials = de.Properties["initials"];

       if(initials != null && initials.Count > 0)
       {
          string theInitials = de.Properties["initials"][0].ToString();
       }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I wish I could vote your answer up but I don't have enough reputation yet :(

Comment: @ShehabFawzy: thanks! That also gives you 2 extra reputation points :-)